# Width set to 100% seems to not working for me.Help me to make my website responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, mobile-website, responsiveness

I,m making a portfolio website for myself as my first project. It looks great on a desktop. But when I open it on mobile it's not responsive. I have tried the width set to 100% But on mobile, I have minimized it to adjust it for the screen, and then it's okay. I want to solve this problem, any help would be appreciated. Here is the website(https://portfoliofirst-website--tammanaaps.repl.co) and here is the code (https://replit.com/@tammanaaps/portfoliofirst-website)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, the container is fix-sized, that's not very responsive. By the way you can benefit from using [CSS grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) both for the container and for different sections on mobile screens together with [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

For instance:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .header-text-box {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1;
}

img {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 2;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, For all of your help.It worked

Answer (score 0):

because you use a container size (960 px)
try to give it the full size of the body (100 %).

```
.container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```